# General ODE question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the general solution $y(t)$ of the ordinary differential equation
>   $$y''+\omega^2 y=\cos \omega t,$$
>   where $\omega>0$.

I'm relatively new to ODEs and PDEs but can someone show me the general steps to do here for this question? Thanks.

Comment: If you are new to ODEs than you have no business solving a task like this one... You need to first read the theory on ODEs before you can solve them...

Comment: I meant new as in I started the course this week

Comment: I'm just used to solving ODEs like y'' + 4y' + 3y = 2sin(x). I'm confused at what to do with the ω on the LHS

Comment: so you are now entering non-homogeneous ode area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the answers by David Quinn and Terry Lee are correct. That's not my issue. But what I find disturbing is that there is *no heuristics* for the particular solution $y_p$ . It just drops out of the blue sky. So I'm actually asking: **why** is the PI of the form $y=t(P\cos\omega t+Q\sin\omega t)$ ?

[Operator Calculus](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/jaar2015/operator.htm) provides us with the desired heuristics, as will be demonstrated now.
The differential
equation shall be written in operator form as:
$$ \left[ \left( \frac{d}{dt} \right)^2 + \omega^2 \right] y(t) = \cos(\omega\,t) $$
By decomposing into factors:
$$ \left(\frac{d}{dt} - i\,\omega \right)
   \left(\frac{d}{dt} + i\,\omega  \right) y(t) = \cos(\omega\,t) $$
We are going to use a *basic formula* in Operator Calculus (see reference):
$$ \large \overline{\underline{ \left| \; \frac{d}{dx} + f = e^{-\int f \, dx}\,
           \frac{d}{dx}\, e^{+\int f \, dx } \; \right| }} $$
As follows:
$$ \frac{d}{dt} + i\,\omega =
   e^{- \int i\,\omega \, dt}\ \frac{d}{dt} \ e^{ + \int i\,\omega \, dt}
= e^{- i\,\omega\, t} \ \frac{d}{dt} \ e^{+ i\,\omega\, t } $$
And likewise:
$$ \frac{d}{dt} - i\,\omega = e^{+ i\,\omega\, t} \ \frac{d}{dt} \ e^{- i\,\omega\, t } $$
Giving for the O.D.E.:
$$ e^{+ i\,\omega\ t } \ \frac{d}{dt} \ e^{- i\,\omega\ t } \
   e^{- i\,\omega\ t } \ \frac{d}{dt} \ e^{+ i\,\omega\ t } \ y(t) = \cos(\omega\,t) $$
Systematic integration is possible now. It's a bit cumbersome, but straightforward:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \ e^{ - 2\,i\,\omega\, t } \frac{d}{dt}\ e^{ + i\,\omega\, t } y(t) =
e^{ - i\,\omega\, t } \cos(\omega\,t) =
e^{ - i\,\omega\, t } \frac{e^{+ i\,\omega\, t} + e^{- i\,\omega\, t}}{2} =
\frac{1 + e^{- 2\,i\,\omega\, t}}{2}
$$ $$
e^{ - 2\,i\,\omega\, t } \frac{d}{dt}\ e^{ + i\,\omega\, t } y(t) =
\int \frac{1 + e^{- 2\,i\,\omega\, t}}{2}\, dt =
\frac{1}{2}\left[ t + \frac{1}{- 2\,i\,\omega}\ e^{- 2\,i\,\omega\, t}\right] + C_1
$$ $$
\frac{d}{dt}\ e^{ + i\,\omega\, t } y(t) = 
\frac{1}{2}\left[ t\ e^{2\,i\,\omega\, t}  + \frac{1}{- 2\,i\,\omega}\right] + C_1 \ e^{2\,i\,\omega\, t }
$$ $$
e^{ + i\,\omega\, t } y(t) =
\frac{1}{2} \int t \ e^{2\,i\,\omega\, t } \, dt - \int \frac{dt}{4\,i\,\omega} +
C_1 \int e^{2\,i\,\omega\, t } \, dt = \frac{1}{4\,i\,\omega} \int t \, d\left(e^{2\,i\,\omega\, t }\right)
- \frac{t}{4\,i\,\omega} + \frac{C_1}{2\,i\,\omega} \ e^{2\,i\,\omega\, t } + C_2 \\
= \frac{t}{4\,i\,\omega} \, e^{2\,i\,\omega\, t } - \frac{1}{4\,i\,\omega} \int e^{2\,i\,\omega\, t } \, dt
- \frac{t}{4\,i\,\omega} + \frac{C_1}{2\,i\,\omega} \ e^{2\,i\,\omega\, t } + C_2 =
\frac{t}{4\,i\,\omega} \, e^{2\,i\,\omega\, t } + \frac{1}{8\,\omega^2} \ e^{2\,i\,\omega\, t }
- \frac{t}{4\,i\,\omega} + \frac{C_1}{2\,i\,\omega} \ \ e^{2\,i\,\omega\, t } + C_2
$$
So finally:
$$
y(t) = \left\{\frac{t}{2\,\omega}\frac{e^{+ i\,\omega\, t} - e^{- i\,\omega\, t}}{2\,i}\right\}
+ \left\{ \left[ \frac{1}{8\,\omega^2} + \frac{C_1}{2\,i\,\omega} \right] \, e^{i\,\omega\, t}
+ C_2 \, e^{- i\,\omega\, t}\right\}
$$
The particular solution is the first one between $\left\{ \right\}$ :
$$
y_p(t) = \frac{t\sin(\omega\,t)}{2\,\omega}
$$
The homogeneous solution is the second one between $\left\{ \right\}$ , the one with the arbitrary constants $C1,C_2$ involved. It is equivalent with $\;y=A\ \cos(\omega\ t)+B\ \sin(\omega\ t)$ .

Answer (score 1):

For the complementary function you are solving $u^2+\omega^2=0$ which gives $y=A\cos\omega t+B\sin \omega t$.
However, for the particular integral, this is a "failure case", so you need to use a PI of the form $$y=t(P\cos\omega t+Q\sin\omega t)$$

Comment: Can the question work both ways using this and the Laplace transformation?

Comment: @TerryLee David has used the [method of undetermined coefficents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients) here to solve your non-homogeneous ODE. A [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) is _another_ way to solve your ODE. Both methods will give the same solution. I suggest you look at videos on youtube by Dr Chris Tisdell, he thoroughly explains both methods.

Comment: for the particular intengral, I don't get where the t comes from. In my table I have kcosωt or ksinωt = Acosωt + Bsinωt. And the coefficient in front of cosωt is 1.

Comment: Can someone confirm if my answer is correct.

I get y''p = -Aω^2sinωt - Bω^2cosωt.  substitute into ODE. But when I do I equate -Bω^2 + Bω^2 = 1 =0. ???

Comment: @TerryLee.you need to check out the failure case, or "resonance" as it also known. Maybe you haven't got there yet in your course.

Comment: sorry to bother you guys again, but I used the resonance thing and arrived at -2Aω = 0 and 2Bω = 1 => B= 1/2ω. So is the final answer C1cosωt + C2sinωt + t/2ω *sinωt

Comment: Yes I agree with that!